# Is there a better way to load images onto a website other than the img tag?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there was a better way to load images to a HTML file other than the `<img>` tag. I ask this because I am building a website that has a photo gallery. This photo gallery has 48 pictures and it seems to take forever to load.

Here is my HTML code for this page:

```
<!--IMAGES-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="AfricaPictures/Africabound_1.JPG"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 "> 
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0226.JPG"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 "> 
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0232.JPG"> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0299.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0330.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0364.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0374.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0392.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0425.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0480.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0543.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0548.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0566.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSC_0615.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN0841.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN0902.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN0909.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN0914.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN0929.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN0957.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN0970.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1024.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1034.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1065.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1095.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1099.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1128.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1130.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1134.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1179.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1221.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1283.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1312.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1313.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1342.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1404.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1417.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1528.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1541.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1623.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/DSCN1624.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/IMG_1836.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/IMG_1849.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/Photo May 14, 01 17 06.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/Photo May 14, 01 22 01.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/Photo May 14, 02 05 57.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/Photo May 14, 02 28 54.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                <img src="AfricaPictures/Photo May 14, 03 54 52.JPG">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<head>
```

As you can see, this is a monstrous three-hundred and sixteen lines of code. There must be a better way and I hope you will share it with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the images has an equal size?

Comment: Most of them are the same size but, as you can see I wrapped them all in a thumbnail class from bootstrap.

Comment: You could try this structure, https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/cr7vbb3b/, it will save you markup and might speed things up. If it is possible to give images a size (as done in the fiddle using percent) they normally load faster as the browser doesn't have to calculate everything by itself. Giving the images a fixed with, as in `px` will load them even faster

Comment: Ok thanks for your assistance LGSon!

Comment: You're welcome. ... 48 images isn't that much, though you could take a look at _lazy loading_: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/

Comment: I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<img>`-element is the one to go for.

Be aware (if not already) that photos on the web should'nt exceed something like 500kb in file size (as a rule of thumb at least). Meaning you need reduce photo-size and kick out pixels. Here is a sample website where you can do it:
http://jpeg-optimizer.com/

Comment: This really helped out! Thanks a ton! My webpage is now loading really fast!

Answer (score 0):

As per the definition of HTML, `<img>` tags are one way to load image. You can also use background images, figures and the sort but the end result will be the same and there must always be a container to contain the image.

There is a lot of code going on there but sadly, the end result is a bit unavoidable. If you use rendering tools, it gives you the illusion that you are not managing it but in the end, the printed result will likely be the same once the code is rendered.

---

For your solution, there's a away to save a few lines left and right:

You can only wrap all your bootstrap columns in one row, since they are using float rules, you will save up a bit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, `img` tag is not the only way, so you need to update that part in your answer

Comment: Good point, probably lacking coffee when I wrote this statement.